# jsp function tag to replace '

Tags: css, spring, jsp, include

Here is my code,

**css/index.jsp:**

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/common/css/common.jsp" %>
<style type="text/css">
    body{background: #ffffff url('<c:url value='/resources/images/logo/logo_small.png'/>') no-repeat scroll center center}
</style>
```

**index.jsp page calls the above css/index.jsp page:**

```
<c:set var="my_css">
    <c:if test="${branch == 'sitemap'}">
        <c:if test="${page == 'index'}">
            <%@include file="/WEB-INF/common/css/sitemap_common.jsp" %>
            <%@include file="/WEB-INF/common/css/index.jsp" %>
        </c:if>
    </c:if>
</c:set>
<c:set var="css" value='${fn:replace(fn:replace(fn:replace(my_css,"<style type=\\\"text/css\\\">", ""),"</style>", ""),"\'", "99999")}'/>
<compress:css enabled="true">
    <c:out value='${css}'/>
</compress:css>
```

In my project there are 100's of jsp pages that return css code. Why i'm doing this is to place my css as a link tag in head section.

In  my code ' is replaced with 99999, but when i change 99999 to & #.. ; return & amp;#..; how to replace?

If there is a better option to convert my jsp to make it as a css link in html head section, please post here. You please post your suggestions too.

Comment: @stackoverflow : why not just delete the style tag from jsp? answer: i'm using ide to for css works. My project is allready hosted and running. now i need to modify for better performance.

Comment: I'm dynamicall generating css and js file using jsp. What i need is i need to place this (generated css) in a link tag in head section, not in script tag.

Answer (score 1):

> now i need to modify for better performance

Modify the the css with some tool or maybe even with some simple java program before you upload it to the server.
Then:

- you do not need to spend time with this problem
- the performance is much better (you do not need any replace stuff while runtime for every request)

Comment: Yes this is what i'm trying to do. Can you please tell me the tool name or java program.

Comment: I think this can be achieved by using templating such as velocity. Up to now i'm not using template for this project.

Comment: I think more of a simple string replace program.

Comment: My problem solved in another way: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14258558/1958355)