# i'm dynamically generating css and js using jsp/jstl/spring. How to place this result in link tag at head section. not in script tag in head section

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, render

I'm generating css in jsp and the output is:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{background: #ffffff url('<c:url value='/resources/images/logo/logo_small.png'/>') no-repeat scroll center center}
</style>
```

Now i'm call this code in jsp using:

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/common/css/sitemap_common.jsp" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/common/css/index.jsp" %>
```

It works and the out put is something like this:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body{background: #ffffff url('<c:url value='/resources/images/logo/logo_small.png'/>') no-repeat scroll center center}
</style>
</head>
```

But what i need is

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mycss.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

THis is a completed project with 100's of css generating jsp. and i need to update for better performance. link tag will be catched in browser. but script tag will load every time.

Comment: Any you generating anything other than absolute URLs to your images?

Comment: images are static resources in current site located at /resources/**

Comment: Also i have static css,js files at /resources/css/ and /resources/js/ they are ordinary files for template purposes. For dynamic purpuses i use jsp to generate css.

Comment: I achieved this in a new test application. After completing my work, I'll post the code soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this.

I created a new route /resource/css|js , I use internal resource view resolver - (folder).

My link url is moething like **/resource/css/qtn/page1.css**.

In controller /resources/{**type**}/{**page**}.css.

Here i get **type** and **page** values and used this in my **dynamic jsp** page to achieve my result.

For security i *checked the url* is it comes from my own page or not.

**Hint :**

While using **internal resource view resolver** it will throw error when you *pass page values directly to resource url* because sometimes page url will be **/page1/block1** so our controller throws error.

To solve this i passed page values as **/resource/css/qtn/page1.css?sub=${page}**.

In controller we can easily cath this **sub** value and send to our dynamic jsp as **model**.

Comment: @It'sK , Sorry sir, its a very old project. I lost those files. I will try to recreate it, if so, i'll post. Sir, If you solve this, please post your answer. I'll make it as right- after checking.