# URL's In CSS. How to bind to whatever context is currently deployed?

Tags: html, css, spring

I have a very large web code base I'm working on, with multiple projects using Spring and a variety of other frameworks.  I'm pretty new to web dev, so if there are terms here I'm misusing or if there is clarification you require please let me know.

Currently we're examining how centralize as many icons as possible into one project the

.laf project.

My question is in CSS for other projects, I can reference those img files like this:

```
.trash {
    background:url(/demo/static/package/name/laf/images/trash.png) no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Now that root directoy (/demo) changes depending on where we deploy our project.  We don't want to have to change the /demo tag on all image files used in this manner each time we deploy to a different context.

Is there a way in css to reference whatever the deployed context is?  Or is this something we need to handle at higher levels?

Comment: Might be helpful to look into some rewrites with `htaccess`..

Comment: How about using ../../../images/thrash.png?? is it a proper way?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  What would the ../../ achieve?

Comment: @user2757729 I added an answer that should work.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do this (if you're using Java) is to use jsp or a servlet to generate your css.  If going the jsp route and you're using Spring tags, you could use the `<spring:url>` tag to generate context-relative URLs.

I'm sure you could do it using PHP / ruby / whatever Microsoft technology in a similar manner.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726054/is-it-possible-to-use-jsp-jstl-to-generate-dynamic-css-javascript-files) for how to do this in Java.

What you'd basically have is this:

in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in your .css file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<spring:url var="myImage" value="/images/image.png" />

...

.myclass {
    background: url(${myImage});
}
```

When this gets rendered, it becomes:

```
.myclass {
     background: url(/context/images/image.png);
}
```

if your webapp is running in the `/context` context.

Comment: Thanks, this is the most appealing answer so far.  Problem is givin the size of the code base and time constraints I'm not really able to implement this atm.

Comment: Works, but not a great solution in my opinion. Better to use relative URLs as they are most often used in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use relative URLs.

URLs in CSS can be **absolute** (like you do) but can also be **relative**. That's how it's most often used.

Relative URLs start looking from the CSS file they are defined in. So you could use something like this

```
.trash {
    background:url(../images/trash.png) no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Which would (as seen from the URL of the CSS file) traverse one folder up, then into the images folder and then retrieve the trash.png.

This obviously only works if the image folder, as seen from the CSS folder, is at a constant location.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be changed in the serverside, you can't achieve this effect in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for your web server? If possible, you could set up different virtual directories for each environment to solve this.