# Using scriptlets inside a .CSS file?

Tags: css, jsp, embed, scriptlet

suppose I have an inline styling such as below inside a .JSP file:

```
<style>
.bg{
    background-color: <%=application.getAttribute("bgcolor").toString()%>
}
</style>
```

What if I want to make it an external .CSS file instead of using inline styling? I tested it and it doesn't work properly?

Many thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726054/is-it-possible-to-use-jsp-jstl-to-generate-dynamic-css-javascript-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.jsp` files are compiled by the container, so you have to write the you css class in `.jsp` file make sure the response content type is `text/css` and add the JSP file to your html like below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="filename.jsp">
```

Comment: Can I also use the include directive? Like say, I store all my internal styling in another file and instead of using <link href="something.css"> I use the include directive instead?

Comment: You can also do that but it only work in jsp files, but if you have some HTML include directive wont work..