# how to pass context value to css

Tags: html, css, jsp

i have to add background image for my webpage, so i have added below code css for body

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-image: url(../resources/img/background_img.jpg);
}
```

but i have to add background-image as

> url(${context}/resources/img/background_img.jpg);

, where context will be passed from jsp (instead of absolute path). put conext param doesnt work, is there any alternative way or am i doing wrongly. Need help

Comment: you may set in using javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant change your css (unless they are [dynamically generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726054/is-it-possible-to-use-jsp-jstl-to-generate-dynamic-css-javascript-files)) .
You can embed a `<style>` tag though in each of your jsps with css code that has [higher precedence](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) so you could change the style like:

```
<head>
.....
<style>
body {
  background-image: url(${context}) !important;
}
</style>
.....
</head>
```

Or you can use some javascript/jquery code to do that:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image',$('#bgImage').val());
});
```

Where `#bgImage` can be a hidden field generated in your jsp like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="bgImage" value="${context}"/>
```

There are also other ways to do such thing, I just outlined two...

Hope this helps

Comment: this seems to quite nice, this is can be externalized and used in other pages also.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that with CSS. The preferred method would be to add a class to the body depending on the context, then have a matching class that defines the style for that context. For example, in your html

```
<body class="context-1"></body>
```

And in your CSS:

```
body.context-1 {
  background-image: url(/path/to/context-1/image);
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply inline the background image.

```
<body style="background-image: url(/path/to/${context})"></body>
```

Comment: but i have many pages which uses same background image, hence i want it to be in css, rather than inline

Comment: @pappu_kutty My first example uses CSS.